# Simplifying CFG: S -> SS | (S) | ε

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

Is it possible to simplify even more the next CFG?

```
S -> SS | (S) | ε
```

I've removed all the other null and unit productions, but I believe it is possible to simplify it even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
S -> (S)S | ε
```

Does that cover all the bits of the original?

S -> (S) is covered by the second S being ε

S -> SS is either two ε, check; or contains at least one pair of parens, check

Yes, that looks about right. You can choose whether you like (S)S or S(S) better, should work the same.

Note: not very authoritative, I have only a vague idea what I'm talking about

Comment: Thanks! I just started learning CFGs and I was struggling in this exercise. Now I see it clearly.